# Visual Studio 2010 crash when profiling, after analyzing report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, profiling, instrumentation

I am profiling my C# WinForm project in VS 2010, SP1. IDE crashes after profilig is finished and analyzing is done, but results are not yet displayed. I can manualy process my report by cmd: `>VSPerfReport.exe /summary:all "Report111229(4).vsp"`
but i would like to get analysis results in VS also, .csv files generated by tool are not so nice.
Interesting is that VS will crash when I use Instrumentation and Sampling, but not when I use Concurrency.
Some ideas or advices how to fix this?

Comment: I've found this part of Visual Studio unreliable when analysing large logs.

Comment: @watbywbarif I have the same issue, and can reliably recreate this even with really small logs. Some people seem to be able to trace it to some; more specific; underlying error but I can't figure out how.

Comment: You should report the bug to MS, just in case they're not aware of it.

Comment: Will do as soon as bounty is over and no solution found.

Comment: Same issue here with profiling C++ in Visual Studio 2012...

Answer (score 3):

Some people are able to get around this using one of four techniques.

1. disabling all visual experience options in VS 2010 by deselecting the option in Tools --> Options --> Environment --> General | Visual Experience
2. disable HW Acceleration for WPF by setting the registry value `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DisableHWAcceleration` to `1`
3. disable the Concurrency option `Collect resource contention data`
4. select `Enable source server support` in Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General

These all stink but may work long enough to allow you to do what you need

Comment: Thx, I will try this after holidays.

Comment: 2. HW Acceleration was already disabled for Visual studio in 1. so I don't see how this could help? Also I don't have Avalon.Graphics key in registry

Comment: 3. This is important only for Concurrency, and Concurrency works OK for me, crashes occur only in Sampling and Instrumentation.

Comment: Well, this did not help me, but you made some effort, so +50.

Answer (score 1):

**Try excluding the Performance file from source control**

What resolved the problem for me was excluding the Performance file (e.g. Performance.psess) from source control (in our case TFS) and ensuring that none of the .psess and .vsp files are marked read only.

I hope this helps someone else too.

Comment: This did't help neither. I am using svn and .vsp is not managed by subversion nor is marked as read-only. But thx, maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: @watbywbarif - in addition, you may want to try waiting for say 5 seconds before stopping the profiling (do it from VS, not by closing the app) and then wait again before you try to produce the report. This appears to reduce the number of times the crash occurs.

Comment: I was finally able to do Instrumentation profiling by pausing the profiler just after the application has launched, then navigate to the exact place that needs to be profiled, resuming the profiler, and exiting by hitting 'Exit' in the profiler.

Answer (score 0):

another workaround that helped me (MSVS2013) is to open **another instance** of visual studio, and **debug->attach** to the first visual studio process, called devenv.exe. After that, open the profile file in the first studio instance.

Go figure.